# How can I replace "/>XXXXX"/> with "/> within a selection

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace

I have a CSV file which I am editing with Notepad++. There is a section of about 500 consecutive lines where I want to replace `"/>XXXXX"/>` with `"/>` where XXXXX are numbers.

Is there a way to do a Find/Replace All with Notepad++ on only that section?

Comment: If you use regular expression in Replace, you can input `[0-9]` for each number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Select your 500 lines where you want to replace something (not start and end of text)
2. Tick *Regular expression* and ***In selection*** like shown on screenshot
3. Find what: `"/>\d+"/>`  (only `\d+` is [RegEx](http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx) and matches all consecutive numeric characters)
   Replace with: `"/>`

   [image]